# Laravel 5.6 SMTP mail sending on local, but it's not working on live server

Tags: smtp, laravel-5.6

I am trying to send an email using SMTP. It is working on my local server but not on my live server. The error I'm getting is: `Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username`. I had to configure less secure apps from Gmail but still it is not working.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=abcd@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs for details of any error?

Comment: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username.....this error i am getting. i had configure less secure from gmail  but still it is not working.

Comment: You should recheck the credentials you're using on live by trying to login online to gmail with the same. I'm guessing you have some issue there.

Comment: same .env file i had sync to live with same credential and its working on local but not on live.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your server via SSH. Locate the project directory, on your production server edit `.env` file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST= { Your HOST } 
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME= { UserName }
MAIL_PASSWORD= { Password }
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS={ From Address }
MAIL_FROM_NAME= { Desired From Name  "Demo" }
```

save and close file.Then, use following command on production server:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

It worked for me. Give reply if you find it useful.

Or still if you are facing issue